# Matlab setting print size of figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I know there are lots of questions on matlab printing questions, but I can't seem to figure this out.

I want to print/save my figure at 17x23cm printed. With a resolution of 600dpi.

I've tried this

```
set(gcf, 'Units', 'centimeters', 'Position', [0 0 17 23], 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters', 'PaperSize', [17 23]);
```

I'm then using the export_fig script and do either of the following

```
export_fig Test.pdf -pdf -transparent;
export_fig Test.pdf -pdf -transparent -r600;
```

Either way, I get a figure that is ~14x19 cm.  And the resolution is only 100dpi.

So I thought, okay 600dpi for a 17cm figure is ~4,000 pixels.  So lets just set the figure on screen to be that many pixels

```
set(gcf, 'Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [0 0 4000 5500]);
```

But that doesn't work. I assume because my monitor isn't big enough to support that many pixels, so it won't display. And I can't then save it because the figure doesn't even show up.

I know I can resize after in gimp or illustrator or whatever. But I don't really want to.

How do I export/save a pdf/eps graph at a specific print size (17cm) with a specific resolution (600dpi)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing using `export_fig` is going to crop the resulting figure to remove any white space (places where your figure has no content). Because of this, the output is going to be smaller than the `Position` that you specify.

To prevent this, you can use the `-nocrop` option.

```
export_fig('Test.pdf', '-pdf', '-nocrop', '-transparent', '-r600')
```

Specifying a resolution is really only intended to have an effect for raster images, for vector graphic formats such as PDF this shouldn't really have an effect. How are you determining the "resolution" of the PDF?

Another option is to just use the built-in `print` function to create your image

```
print('myimage.pdf', '-dpdf', '-loose', '-r600')
```

The `-loose` option here will ensure that it uses a loose bounding box and won't crop the empty regions of your figure, resulting in an image of the dimensions you're prescribing.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, I don't know how I missed it was getting cropped.